# how to parse wordpress post_meta table values

Tags: json, wordpress, parsing

I have to parse wordpress **post_meta**  table , particularly  **"_wp_attachment_metadata" field**

For example:

Its value is for a post id = 99

```
> a:6:{s:5:"width";s:3:"238";s:6:"height";s:3:"179";s:14:"hwstring_small";s:23:"height='96'
> width='128'";s:4:"file";s:21:"2010/11/matt-lane.jpg";s:5:"sizes";a:1:{s:9:"thumbnail";a:3:{s:4:"file";s:21:"matt-lane-150x150.jpg";s:5:"width";s:3:"150";s:6:"height";s:3:"150";}}s:10:"image_meta";a:10:{s:8:"aperture";s:1:"0";s:6:"credit";s:0:"";s:6:"camera";s:0:"";s:7:"caption";s:0:"";s:17:"created_timestamp";s:1:"0";s:9:"copyright";s:0:"";s:12:"focal_length";s:1:"0";s:3:"iso";s:1:"0";s:13:"shutter_speed";s:1:"0";s:5:"title";s:0:"";}}
```

I didnt understand how it is compiled or how it can be parsed outside wordpress. The thing i si have to load the latest articles with all the data sets of post on magento platform from wordpress.

please help me to parse this data to get the images src's.

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you understand how this field is compiled? i'm trying to find a tutorial let me understand it

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try:

```
$a = unserialize("");
print_r($a);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Answer (score 9):

What I understand is:

There are two types of variables, for example:

1. `a:6:`
2. `s:3:`

`a` = array and `6` is the dimension of the array
`s` = string and `3` is the length of the string

Answer (score 3):

Thanks a lot for Craig quick answer.

Used the unserialize method and got everything from the string.

```
Array
(
    [width] => 523
    [height] => 523
    [hwstring_small] => height='96' width='96'
    [file] => 2010/11/tee1.jpg
    [sizes] => Array
        (
            [thumbnail] => Array
                (
                    [file] => tee1-150x150.jpg
                    [width] => 150
                    [height] => 150
                )

            [medium] => Array
                (
                    [file] => tee1-300x300.jpg
                    [width] => 300
                    [height] => 300
                )

            [post-thumbnail] => Array
                (
                    [file] => tee1-523x198.jpg
                    [width] => 523
                    [height] => 198
                )

        )

    [image_meta] => Array
        (
            [aperture] => 0
            [credit] => 
            [camera] => 
            [caption] => 
            [created_timestamp] => 0
            [copyright] => 
            [focal_length] => 0
            [iso] => 0
            [shutter_speed] => 0
            [title] => 
        )

)
```

Here is the output, now can take any image from the wordpress post meta_data